# WPF and protocol-buffers: do they fit together?

Tags: wpf, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

I am wondering what would be the best approach in a WPF (possibly MVVM) based application, where the data exchange with the remote devices is made through Protocol-buffers (if conveniently applies).

WPF is strongly based on observability, as well as the mutability of the underlying model/viewmodel, with DPs and INotify* interfaces. Is it fighting against the protocol-buffer approach of create/mutate POCO's?

The typical context is having a WPF client application, connected via TCP/IP to an embedded device running Linux. Basically, I'm evaluating pros/cons of several solutions in order to find out the best one.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your key points seem to be about mutability and observability.

The google protobuf API is indeed largely immutable and won't love WPF very much; however, you also mention protobuf-net, which is *not* that pattern, and adopts instead standard .NET idioms.

A protobuf-net model can be any standard model you want. If you want it to have notification events... have notification events. It won't mind. I can't remember 100%, but if you are working from a .proto file, I *believe* there is a switch to have to codegen add notification events automatically, but .proto is entirely optional with protobuf-net.

The output from protobuf-net should be entirely interchangeable with any other implementation for your linux device. One option there would be Mono/protobuf-net, but you could use the "standard" implementations too.

Comment: Thank you very much, Marc. I give my point to you, but I'd give to Kent as well (fully respectable).

At the moment I'm still in the decision stage: I must perform some concrete experiment, before choosing any of the potential ways. Of sure, none is highlighting for the ability to interface with WPF.

Do you know anyone has tried anything like this, who may show me some piece of code?

Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

WPF should have zero bearing on this because your data exchange should be separated into a separate, UI-agnostic layer. Your service layer can return non-GPB objects if necessary (or returns interfaces that your GPB objects implement via partial classes), and your view model layer provides yet another layer of insulation.

Comment: Hmmm...Consider having a data-model hosted on the server side, much like a DB. At the client side you should mirror this model, or at least being able to access it in some way. Afterward, you may create your own view-model on it...on what am I wrong on this?
Thanks for your answer anyway...